# Add value to another cell until total value reached

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need an excel formula or VBA to solve below problem. So I need you guys to help me please:)

My problem is :

I have a table as blow with given total request and values. What I need is generate new value and the total of those values should give me closest total to  "Total Request"

So the generation of new values should stop when it reach >= Total request.

Given Table :

```
Total Request   35

Value   New Value   
1       
2       
3       
14      
21      
12
```

Requested Table

```
Total Request   35

Value   New Value   
1       1
2       2
3       3
14      14
21      
12
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You dont want to get over the *Total Request*? The sum of *New Value* in *Requested Table* is =20.

Comment: Yes because if I get the next one the total will be 41.

Answer (score 2):

### IF SUM in expanding range

Presuming you have *Value* column as column A, you can use this formula and copy down. It should stop on sum=20:

```
=IF(SUM($A$5:A5)<Total_Request;SUM($A$5:A5);"")
```

Or if you want just the value as an answer:

```
=IF(SUM($A$5:A5)<Total_Request;A5;"")
```

[image]